# Connect Genymotion and Physical Android phone like P2P

Tags: android, p2p, genymotion

Is there a way to connect my android phone to genymotion like a p2p connection? I'm trying to unlock my phone using p2p adb, but the only rooted android device I have is a virtual device, named genymotion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the Genymotion Soft.

- Create a virtual device,
- Open the device's settings panel,
- At the bottom you will find a "Network Mode" section, set it to Bridge,
- On the dropdown menu on the right choose your network interface (wifi or Ethernet),
- Start your device, it should now be exposed on your local network

Then connect your device on Wifi on the same local network than your computer and your all set.

You can get the local IP addresses of the devices from the Settings app or through command line:

```
adb shell "ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr(\$2,6)}' | awk 'NR==2'"
```